# How to load Image using Skiasharp in Tizen watch using C#

Tags: xamarin, tizen, skiasharp

I'm using C# Xamarin, and SkiaSharp to render image from resource folder. But I cannot get the correct image location.
[image]

Where I can find this image when run project? I try to looking for but no result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get resource directory path using DirectoryInfo

https://samsung.github.io/TizenFX/API4/api/Tizen.Applications.DirectoryInfo.html#Tizen_Applications_DirectoryInfo_Resource

Here is a example that how to use

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/b59bb767a4367240983e93ab8e1a9a050dfea23b/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen/ResourcePath.cs#L27-L30

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Seungkenun Le. Base on his comment, I write a simple function to get resource path in Tizen Watch for Xamarin:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the resource path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static string GetResourcePath()
    {
        Tizen.Applications.Application app = Tizen.Applications.Application.Current;
        if (app != null)
        {
            string resourcePath = app.DirectoryInfo.Resource;
            if (Directory.Exists(resourcePath))
            {
                return resourcePath;
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```